# Slack Uploader Plugin: Jenkins can't find file location

Tags: jenkins, plugins, slack

i have an issue that Jenkins can't file location after build the apk. Even though i already set the file location in the right place see the picture. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

write full path your .apk
this error is occured it can't found your file